# how to reference a cell's location in excel VBA

Tags: excel, formula, vba

If I'm trying to put this formula into a column of cells, how to I reference a given cell's location without adding a column of numbers with each cell's location?

here's the excel formula:

```
=SUMIF($B$1:B9,B9,$H$1:H9)
```

In VBA I need something like:

```
credTot.Formula = "=SUMIF(2:" & credTotColumn & ", RC[-3]...."
```

how do I lock up the top row, but also reference the row the relevant cell is in?

Comment: something like this: `credTot.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(R1C[-3]:RC[-3],RC[-3],R1C[3]:RC[3])"`? If `credTot` refers to, say, `E9`, it gives you `=SUMIF(B$1:B9,B9,H$1:H9)`

Answer (score 1):

here's what works

```
credTot.Formula = "=SUMIF(R1C[-7]:RC[-7], RC[-7], R1C[-1]:RC[-1])"
```